# How to create the API error response format same like the default format?

Tags: c#, api

For example, in my C# model, I have

```
public class Account
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }     
}
```

Note: `AccountType` is C# enum

When I test it using Postman with POST request like below,

```
{
    "AccountType": "a",    
    "Name": "John"
}
```

The error response is 400 Bad Request

```
{
    "accountType": [
        "Error converting value \"a\" to type 'Models.App.Enum.AccountType'. Path 'AccountType', line 2, position 22."
    ]
}
```

Now, I have manual validation for `Name` property.

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(account.Name))
{
    return BadRequest("Name is required");
}
```

But when I test it using Postman with POST request like below,
{
"AccountType": "1",
"Name": ""
}

The error response is 400 Bad Request

```
Name is required
```

My question is how to I manually write my `Name` validation so that the error response format will be like similar format like `AccountType`? This is so that front end developer can get the error message from standardized error response format. or should I manually write validation for `AccountType` to match with `Name` format?

Answer (score 2):

You can create anonymous object and pass that object as result.

```
return BadRequest(new { Name = new string[] {"Name is Required"} });
```